# Generar Código QR y asociarlo a un recurso( archivo pdf, jpeg, mp4, almacenados en BDD) , luego almacenar ese QR en la base de datos

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, qr

mi inquietud es acerca de cómo poder implementar una funcionalidad que implica generar un código QR para un archivo que tengo almacenado en mi base de datos, mi modelo es el siguiente:

```
class Recurso(models.Model):
id_recurso= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
nombre= models.CharField(max_length=255)
descripcion= models.TextField()
tipo_recurso= models.ForeignKey('TipoRecurso', db_column='id_tipo_recurso')
id_usuario= models.ForeignKey('Usuario', db_column='id_usuario')
archivo_recurso = models.FileField(upload_to='recursos/')
tag_recurso= models.ForeignKey('TagRecurso',db_column='id_tag')
qrcode = models.ImageField(upload_to='recursos/', blank=True, null=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.nombre
```

Mis datos se almacenan correctamente en la base de datos, permitiendo un campo en este caso **qrcode** como null, ya que lo que deseo es que al dar clic en un botón, **Generar QR** en la vista, donde presento a lista de recursos, me genere para cada recurso un código QR y almacenarlo en el campo **qrcode** en mi base de datos con la información asociada a ese recurso: nombre, descripción tipo, etc.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor si alguien me puede dar alguna orientación al respecto agradecería mucho, que sería lo más recomendable:
¿jquery? ¿ajax? (aunque para ser sincero no soy un experto en esto) , 
o si es que se puede hacer directamente desde alguna función en python.

Quedo atento a cualquier ayuda. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, ¿qué estás usando para generar el QR?

Comment: hola, estoy intentando con qrcode que es una librería para python que permite generar QR, pero no se si sea más conveniente realizarlo con un js, estoy en ese dilema. o que me podrías recomendar?

Comment: Yo personalmente utilizo algo parecido, pero al igual que tú, tengo una lista de recursos y una URL preparada para que cuando se haga una petición de lectura al recurso, se muestre / descargue o lo que se necesite. El código QR es un simple enlace que indica el código del recurso a leer y la url para ello (que puede ser dinámica). Así que realmente el código QR no es más que la concatenación de la URL para la lectura + el ID del recurso, por lo que no se almacena en ningún lado. Cuando lo muestro (como en tú botón Generar), simplemente hago que esa URL se muestre como QR.

Answer (score 0):

Hice algo parecido.
Mi idea fue algo tan simple como poner el Code_qr dentro del UpdateView. (En mi modelo no tengo el campo Code_qr).

En este ejemplo sólo hago que coja el codigo.

Primer descargo esta librería [code_qr](https://mega.nz/#!IltGkayQ!HBaIWblwG2kXJphJPCm2QDhjQyc7BaSrs-W1ovKi9lA)

En mi html:

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="row titulo-general">
                            <legend>Code QR</legend>
                        </div>
                        <fieldset class="col-md-7 col-xs-9" style="text-align: center !important; left: 120px !important;">
                            <div class="table-responsive res-table">
                                <table class="table table-vcenter table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
                                    <div class="border-fieldset">
                                        <div class="container" style="padding: 15px !important; margin-top: auto !important; top: 30% !important;">
                                            <div class="codigoqr" id="qrcode">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
```

JS:

```
        $(function(){
            new QRCode("qrcode", {
                text: "{{ object.codigo }}",
                width: 300,
                height: 300
            });
        });
```

Espero que te ayude en algo :').

PD: No se te olvide importar la librería

```
<script src="{% static 'js/qr_code/qrcode.min.js' %}"></script>
```